# Linear independence question involving sets

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S$ is a subset of a vector space $V$ such that $S$ is linearly independent and $S = W_1 \cup W_2$. Then would $W_1$ be independent and $W_2$ be independent on their own? If so, why?

Comment: Hint: every subset of a linearly independent subset is linearly independent.

Comment: @vadim123 : But that is what is to be proved here.

Answer (score 4):

If the zero vector can be written as a nonzero linear combination of members of $W_1$, then it can be written as a nonzero linear combination of members of $S$, since every member of $W_1$ is a member of $S$.

In otherwords, if $W_1$ is not linearly independent, then neither is $S$.

Thus if $S$ is linearly independent, then so is $W_1$.  And $W_2$, for the same reason.

Comment: Maybe you could say specifically that you can use zero coefficients in a linear combination so as to formally include in the combination vectors (like those of $W_2$) that are not actually needed; that is the main point here.